# Peculiar listbox.Requery visual bug

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I have a listbox which filters upon `AfterUpdate` event based on a value in combobox. All works fine, except sometimes it doesn't show all records properly.

However, if I were to simply click on a line in the listbox, it correct itself.

Moreover, the way it shows the data when it bugs out is very peculiar - it shows last column fully but rest of the data is messed up.

Any idea how to solve this? I have a simple `Me.listBoxName.Requery` as last lane in `cboObjedn_AfterEvent()` and never had problem before doing it this way.

I have attached 2 pictures showing an example (usually there are 10+ rows, not 2).[image: Before clicking on the row of data]

[image: After clicking on the row of data]

Edit:
The code for the AfterUpdate sub is as follows:

```
Private Sub cboOrder_ID_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mSQL(Me))
    Set Me.lst1Model_Operation.Recordset = rst
    Me.lst1Model_Operation.Requery

End Sub
```

And:

```
Public Property Get mSQL(object As Object) As String
mySQL = "SELECT MO.Model_Operation_ID, MO.Model_ID, MO.Operation_Value_ID, OV.Operation_Name_ID, OL.Operation_Name AS Operácia, OM.Quantity AS [Poèet párov], " & "Format([OV].[Value], " & """0.0000 €""" & ")" & "AS Sadzba, OM.Order_ID, OM.Order_Name, ML.Model_Name" _
        & " FROM tbl2ModelsList AS ML INNER JOIN (tbl3OperationsList AS OL INNER JOIN (tbl2Operation_Value AS OV INNER JOIN (tbl1Model_Operation AS MO INNER JOIN tbl1Order_Model AS OM ON MO.Model_ID = OM.Model_ID) ON OV.Operation_Value_ID = MO.Operation_Value_ID) ON OL.Operation_ID = OV.Operation_Name_ID) ON ML.Model_ID = OM.Model_ID" _
        & " WHERE (((OM.Order_ID)=" & object.cboOrder_ID & "))"
End Property
```

Comment: Did you do a Requery? Or simply set the ListBox RowSource?

Comment: @PaulFrancis first I set a ListBox RowSource then I requery (all in AfterUpdate event).

Comment: What happens if you just assign the query statement to the list box's `RowSource` property, like this?  ... `Me.lst1Model_Operation.RowSource = mSQL(Me)`

Comment: @HansUp it seems to work, however, the problem arose seldom as it were already, so I will let you know if it comes back =). Thanks ^_^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the query statement to the list box's *RowSource* property:

```vb
Me.lst1Model_Operation.RowSource = mSQL(Me)
```

Changing the *RowSource* updates the list box contents in response to the updated `SELECT` statement, so you don't need to call `Requery` again in your code.